# Problema gerar PHP/HTML para PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

Tenho um gerador de certificados que são implementados com HTML/PHP

Usei o DOMPDF porém ele não atribui a variável `$html=' <codigo todo> ';` ele dá erro nos comandos IF's depois que atribuo a variável. Igual mostra nas documentações e vários tutoriais na internet, o meu dá o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/aplicacoes/declaracao2/certificado/105/certificado.php on line 265

Nessa linha contém: um `IF = if ($obj->id=='81'){?>`

Usei o `buffer ob_start;` ele funciona, porém ele fica muito fora da página, preciso ajustar ele. Mas tem alguns certificados que aparecem a mensagem:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_cellmap() on a non-object in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/aplicacoes/declaracao2/certificado/100/dompdf/include/table_cell_frame_reflower.cls.php on line 30

Já tentei MPDF também, porém ele só faz a imagem de fundo e os campos dos dados certificados não aparecem.

O que fazer?

Código do `certificado.php`:

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
ob_start();
if ($obj->cpf == $doc) //isset($certificado_numero) and ($certificado_numero<>''))
{
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<link href="unidade.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">

}



</style>
</head>

<body>

<table width="1070" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <div class="anterior">
    <td width="1068" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #666666;" align="center">
<img src="<?= $imagem; ?>" width="1070" height="698" /></td>
    </div>
  </tr>
 </table>

<div id='posiciona1'><?= utf8_decode($participante)?></div>
<div id='posiciona2'><b><?=$obj->num_certificado?></b></div>
<div id='posiciona4'><b><?= $horario; ?></b></div>
<div id='posiciona5'><? echo $observacoes."<p>"; ?></div>


</body>

<?

}
else
{
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   alert( 'Este Certificado ainda n�o foi registrado. Aguarde!');
   self.close();
  </script>

<?
}
?>
</html>
<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("newfile.pdf");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dizia Hannibal, vamos por partes.

### Seu Código

Seu código teve a aproximação errada do problema. Ora que você tenta chamar o HTML e depois rendenizar o seu `DOMPDF`.

Você deverá colocar todo o seu conteúdo HTML dentro de um avariável, por exemplo:

```
$htmlPagina = "
<table width="1070" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>
    <div class="anterior">
    <td width="1068" style="border-bottom: 0px solid #666666;" align="center">
<img src="<?= $imagem; ?>" width="1070" height="698" /></td>
    </div>
  </tr>
 </table>

<div id='posiciona1'><?= utf8_decode($participante)?></div>
<div id='posiciona2'><b><?=$obj->num_certificado?></b></div>
<div id='posiciona4'><b><?= $horario; ?></b></div>
<div id='posiciona5'><? echo $observacoes."<p>"; ?></div>"
```

Saliento que seu código `<?= utf8_decode($participante)?>` retornará erro, ou melhor, não retornará nada por vezes. Para resolver isso, escreva da seguinte forma: `<? echo utf8_decode($participante)?>`.

Devo identificar para você que as variáveis presentes no HTML deverão ser saneadas (preenchidas) antes da passar a instrução para o `DOMPDF`, ou seja, você deverá te-las armazenadas e instanciadas previamente.

### Código do DOMPDF

Não vou me alongar nesse quesito porque sua aplicação é bastante simples. 
Para rendenizar e criar um arquivo de Certificado, use o treco a seguir:

```
// Incluímos a biblioteca DOMPDF
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

// Instanciamos a classe
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

// Passamos o conteúdo que será convertido para PDF
$dompdf->load_html($html);

// Definimos o tamanho do papel e
// sua orientação (retrato ou paisagem)
$dompdf->set_paper('A4','portrait');

// O arquivo é convertido
$dompdf->render();

// Salvo no diretório temporário do sistema
// e exibido para o usuário
$dompdf->stream("nome-do-arquivo.pdf");
```

### Seu JS

Você poderá fazer uma página HTML com o seu *JS* de forma preliminar ao chamamento do PHP.

Para tal você poderá fazer com que o *script js* permita, ou não, a abertura do arquivo e sua compilação.

---

**Dica**: Você poderá chamar as variáveis de PHP normalmente, como se faz em uma *query*; e também poderá chamar o arquivo HTML de forma externa, ou seja, escrever o HTML em uma página separada e mandar o PHP ler o arquivo e dar um `fopen` nele.

Se bater alguma dúvida quanto à nomenclatura ou indentação, veja a [documentação do DOMPDF no Google Doc](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)

Answer (score 0):

Tenho usado em meus últimos projetos a classe **pdfcrowd**, e não tive problemas.

**Installation**

Copy **pdfcrowd.php** to your source directory.

**Example**

Server side PDF generation. This code converts a web page and sends the generated PDF to the browser (don't forget to use your "username" and "apikey"):

```
require 'pdfcrowd.php';

try
{   
    // create an API client instance
    $client = new Pdfcrowd("username", "apikey");

    // convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable
    $pdf = $client->convertURI('http://example.com/');

    // set HTTP response headers
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Accept-Ranges: none");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"created.pdf\"");

    // send the generated PDF 
    echo $pdf;
}
catch(PdfcrowdException $e)
{
    echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}


// Other basic operations:
// convert an HTML string
$html = "<html><body>In-memory HTML.</body></html>";
$pdf = $client->convertHtml($html);

// convert an HTML file
$pdf = $client->convertFile('/path/to/local/file.html');
```

O mesmo pode ser encontrado e baixado [aqui](https://github.com/pdfcrowd/pdfcrowd-php)